# Vertically centered elements in toolbars html/css

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have two button bars- each contains links, but one also contains a submit button of a certain height. The one with the submit button has all the elements vertically centered. I want the other button bar, without the submit button, to look the same, so I gave it an explicit height. However, the links within it align to the top instead of in the middle.

What's going on here, and how can I make link bars that are of a consistent height, with vertically centered elements?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="link-bar">
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
</div>

<div class="link-bar">
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type='submit'] {
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    border:solid red 1px;
}
.link-bar {
    height:40px;
    background:#EEE;
    border:blue 1px solid;
    margin:10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLqbk/5/) for example

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `line-height` equal to the `height`.  By default, any text on that line will be vertically centered.  The exception occurs if you wrap the text to a new line.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/line-height

I also removed your `vertical-align` as it's superfluous to content in block level elements.  [It only applies to inline elements](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align).

```
.link-bar {
    height: 40px;
    background: #EEE;
    border:blue 1px solid;
    margin: 10px;
}

.link-bar a {
    line-height: 40px; /* equal to the height of the container */
}
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/SLqbk/9/

Comment: BTW I ended up combining `line-height` with `display:inline-block` for an even better solution- see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8873053/165673)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height) property.

```
.link-bar a {
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SLqbk/7/

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css

```
.link-bar a {line-height: 40px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xYVRj/

Answer (score 0):

I gave @Sparky672 the answer because he correctly addressed my specific question and led me on the right path, but I want to share what I ended up doing, which I think is more effective overall:

Instead of explicitly setting the line-height of `.link-bar a` to try to match up to the container and button heights, I just set ALL the elements in the toolbar to the same line-height, and make them `display:inline-bock`. While the normal caveats of using inline-block apply (See [here](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) and [here](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/)), the end result is consistent sizing and vertical centering for all the elements you throw in your toolbar, with less css to manage:

```
.link-bar * {
    line-height: 30px; 
    display:inline-block;
    /* Keep top-bottom padding of elements zeroed for consistent heights: */
    padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0; 
}
```

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLqbk/13/).

[image]